# Ms Access SQL How to eliminate duplicate values

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have reviewed so many similar looking posts here that my head is spinning, but none seem to address this particular issue, but that may be that I didn't understand the answer.
The query below produces results with duplicate s.ID records due to the join over the c Table. What is the best way to eliminate rows in the result set with duplicate s.ID values? I would prefer to keep those duplicate records with MAX(c.ID) and eliminate the others.

```
Select (o.fld1 & ' ' & o.fld2) as Name, 
  g.name, 
  (Select Count(*) from sd where s.ID=sd.ID) as TheCount, 
  sm.*, 
  l.name, 
  t.name, 
  s.ID, 
  s.name, 
  c.ID
From ((((((
  s Inner Join c on s.fld2=c.fld2) 
  Inner Join o on s.oID=o.ID) 
  Inner Join g on s.gID=g.ID) 
  Left Join sm on s.smID=sm.ID) 
  Inner Join l on s.lID=l.ID) 
  Inner Join t on s.tID=t.ID) 
Where c.fld3 IN (1,3,5)
Order By s.ID ASC, c.ID ASC
```

This is a simplification, but I think it catches all the core elements. For example, the select clause has more items but at least one embedded SQL query and one constructed field name and one 'table.*' as in the example; and the Where clause can be much more complicated depending on user-defined filter criteria.

Example result rows might be:

```
s.ID    c.ID   ...
1       1
1       3
2       3
2       5
```

I would like rows #1 and #3 not returned in the result set. Keeping the rows with MAX(c.ID) on duplicate s.ID rows.

Comment: By removal of duplicates do you mean the removal of some records from the database, or just avoiding to show duplicates? Also, what is duplicated? Everything cannot be, since c.ID is identified as a field which differs from result record to result record.

Comment: Remove rows from the result set of this query that have duplicate s.ID values.

Comment: The s table record is duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check in your `where` clause for the non-existence of an s-c pair with higher `c.ID` value

```
Select (o.fld1 & ' ' & o.fld2) as Name, 
  g.name, 
  (Select Count(*) from sd where s.ID=sd.ID) as TheCount, 
  sm.*, 
  l.name, 
  t.name, 
  s.ID, 
  s.name, 
  c.ID
From ((((((
  s Inner Join c on s.fld2=c.fld2) 
  Inner Join o on s.oID=o.ID) 
  Inner Join g on s.gID=g.ID) 
  Left Join sm on s.smID=sm.ID) 
  Inner Join l on s.lID=l.ID) 
  Inner Join t on s.tID=t.ID) 
Where not exists (select 1 from s s2 join c c2 on s2.fld2=c2.fld2 WHERE s2.ID=s.ID and c2.ID>c.ID and c2.ID IN (1,3,5))
Order By s.DateAndTime ASC, s.fld9 ASC, c.fld4 ASC
```

Comment: I am getting "Syntax error in query expression" and it is flagging the entire Where clause above.

Comment: Ok, I ran with your idea and updated your 'not exists' clause to "(select 1 from s s2 join c c2 on s2.fld2=c2.fld2 WHERE s2.ID=s.ID and c2.ID>c.ID and c2.ID IN (1,3,5))" and that worked! But execution time went from 2 seconds to 16 seconds on a small test database. Yikes. No Bueno.

Comment: @JJJones_3860 indexing some fields might be helpful in this case.

Comment: You are correct Lajos! c.fld2 was not indexed. Once I indexed it, processing time went from 2 seconds originally to 3 seconds (approx). This is quite acceptable. Thx

Comment: It won't let me up-check the answer. It says it is locked unless you edit your answer first.

Comment: @JJJones_3860 added the fix that you have suggested in an earlier coment.